# How to manually (formless) Authenticate user? Cakephp 4x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

User doesn't stay logged in when I use `setIdentity`.

```php
    $user = $this->Users->get(1);
    $this->Authentication->setIdentity($user);
    $userInfo = $this->Authentication->getIdentity(); // Returns good.
    $this->redirect('Somewhere');
```

**Somewhere**:

```php
    $userInfo = $this->Authentication->getIdentity(); // Returns null.
```

I am not using form. There is no POST happening only dynamically setting user based on some algo...

`Application.php`

```php
public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
    {
        $service = new AuthenticationService([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/login',
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
        ]);

/*        $fields = [
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password'
        ];

        $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', compact('fields')); */

        // Load the authenticators, you want session first
        $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');

        return $service;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the principal information on the Authentication but you loose it on the next request because it's not persisted (I'm sparing you the "http is stateless" song...)

Part of your `setIdentity` should also be persisting the identity. This can be achieved in different ways:

- in the session, when using sessions
- in a JWT token, when using tokens

Here is how `AuthenticationService` does it in [`persistIdentity`](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/blob/master/src/AuthenticationService.php#L240). I suggest you also have a look at the [JWT auth configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/authenticators.html#jwt).

Comment: Thank you. Actually, turns out, I had upgraded from 4.0-beta to 4.1.4 and that broke how sessions work.